# Refresh a page or navigate to same page in windows phone 8.1 (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I searched but I always find a way for windows phone 8 that doesn't work for windows phone 8.1.
I want to refresh a page or navigate to same page in windows phone 8.1.
I Want to do this on **windows phone 8.1** .
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can make to navigate to the same page by this. this.frame.navigate (currentpagename);

Comment: How can I refresh that page?

Comment: show wat u did in ur Xaml code

Comment: Thanks. I solve my problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I Just change mode of NavigationCacheMode.

```
NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

With this code, I disable cache.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: good. But in this case your app will behave odd when user presses back button after navigating back to first page. user will see send page!

Comment: user will see send page! What is meaning? I can't understand. there is nothing to saved in first page for me.

Answer (score 0):

your first page is already loaded. all you need to do is to GoBack. In your second page where you want to go to first page use this code.

```
   if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                this.Frame.GoBack();
```

Hope this helps.